# Max integral type in C#

Tags: c#, types

I can't seem to find an integral type that this will work on:

```
string foo = "9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999";

long value;
if(long.TryParse(foo, out value))
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: I am saying that the number is too big

Comment: Sorry to whoever gave this is a -1. This seems like a reasonable question and I gave it a +1.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In .NET 4 you can use System.Numerics.BigInteger which has a TryParse method.

See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Yes, .NET 4.0 introduces BigInteger which is arbitrarily large and supports TryParse, of course.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There is not a primative type that will work for that. But there is a new BigInteger class introduced in .NET 4.

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/05/23/net-framework-4-0-introducing-biginteger.aspx

Comment: Ok, bad choice of words. There isn't a type in the system namespace with a simple alias? I think Primitive is the word I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

[BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) is what you're looking for.